# How can I fix this jagged shadow?

Tags: shadows, toon-shading

I'm trying to achieve a toon shading look with hard shadows, but when I turn off soft shadows I get a very jagged shadow around the neck, is there any way to fix this? I've tried upping the render resolution and fiddling with the light source and subdividing the mesh more, but nothing seems to work. Did I just screw up the mesh?[image: Neck Example]

Comment: What's the resolution of your output image? At first sight this looks like normal anti-aliasing on a low-resolution image.. do you have any compositing going on?

Comment: I cropped the image in a photo editor which left it with low resolution, but this render was at 4K resolution and I tried another at 8k and it didnt help, but no compositing